# how to convert data base data to XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, database, linq-to-xml

Q:

I'm a beginner to the XML.I have some data comes from my database, and i wanna to convert these data to `XML` file,to import it to a specific program later..What are the required steps to do this?Please examples and articles if possible?

need some thing like [that](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2009031901&page=1) ,but dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetXml() is the function with DataSet to get xml.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 // fill dataset from database
ds.GetXml();
```

Hope will Help.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add("DataTableName");
ds.GetXml();
```