# Convert from csv to xml in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, csv

My SQL Server database has entire csv file's data saved in varchar field like in following sample:

```
StudentName,Field1,Field2,...,Fieldn
Homer,somevalue,somevalue,...,somevalue
Elmer,somevalue,somevalue,...,somevalue
```

I want to retrieve the data and convert it to html script given as in following sample:

```
<grade>
    <StudentName name='Homer'>
    </StudentName>
    <StudentName name='Elmer'>
    </StudentName>
</grade>
```

Can I do this directly using SQL select statement? If not then what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: dupli : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328010/how-to-convert-data-base-data-to-xml-file

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server

Comment: You could try using many existing SQL Server 'split' functions like ones mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql. Then you could use `FOR XML` to convert that XML. Try that approach and post back any specific issues. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Im having difficulty converting the csv string above into a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select concat('<grade>',t1.stmt,'</grade>' from (select  concat('<StudentName name=''', t.studentname,
              '''> </StudentName>' ) as stmt
from MytableName t) t1
```

NB: you can use any mechanism to concatenate the result and replace concat with that.

Update:

If your each row is saved in different field then you can get name using [charindex](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx) and [left](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx) of t-sql

Comment: I dont have a student table MyTableName, the entire csv is stored as one varchar in the database, headers and all.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Is each line of the csv file is saved in sperate row or entire csv is saved in one field?

Comment: The entire csv is saved as one field

Comment: Oops then my update won't help you. Sorry to say that you need to save the entire string in a programming language then parse it using c++ , php or any language you are comfortable with.

Comment: I have managed to put the csv into a table but am now getting "Incorrect syntax near from" from your sql